# How to tell if light power cord is Low Voltage

Tags: electrical, lighting, code-compliance, low-voltage

I know per code you can't run high voltage power cords behind a wall, but my understanding per this thread [Why can't I (or: shouldn't I) run a power cord through a wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/152088/why-cant-i-or-shouldnt-i-run-a-power-cord-through-a-wall) is below 55 watts I am good. I am looking at buying this product [Light Bulb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D99T4MV) and it says [image] wattage is 8W, am I safe to run this behind my wall.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not low voltage. It's 120VAC.

Comment: It is 120V - no, you can't run it behind a wall

Comment: That light can be hardwired.  Is there a reason to not have an outlet close enough or not to wire a box behind the light?

Answer (score 8):

It is the voltage not wattage.

Low voltage is below ~55v and has very few if any code requirements.

Does not matter if 1 watt or 10000 watts, if the voltage is 120/240 it must be done to code and code says no power cords inside walls.